# How to implement shouldInterceptRequest in Android 4.4.4 or previous versions

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

How can I implement the following WebClient method in in Android 4.4.4 or previous versions:

```
shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
```

N.B : I need this method with the parameter **WebResourceRequest**.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        //Do Stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` does not exist prior to API Level 21 (Android 5.0). If your `minSdkVersion` is below 21, but your `compileSdkVersion` is 21 or higher, you can *implement* that method, but it will only be *called* on Android 5.0+ devices.

For the older devices, you have no choice but to *also* implement [the earlier form of `shouldInterceptRequest()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)). Or, skip this functionality entirely on older devices. Newer devices can still use the newer callback, but you cannot somehow "retcon" older devices to know about `WebResourceRequest` and the older callback.

Comment: Is there any alternative?

Comment: @TH3Under: You could set your `minSdkVersion` to 21 or higher, and drop support for these older devices.

Comment: Did this already, but users are getting upset. (30% of users of the app are using older versions)